# Attachment Missing python 2.7

Tags: python, email, smtp

### Attachment is missing in this script

I am trying to send an attachment using python script, but i don't receive the attachment,its missing,let me know how to get the attachment which is missing now and whats the error in this code

```
import smtplib
import base64

filename = "D:\python/Files_List.txt"

fo = open("Files_List.txt", "rb")
filecontent = fo.read()
encodedcontent = base64.b64encode(filecontent)  # base64

sender = 'rom@domain.com'
reciever = 'to@domain.com'

marker = "AUNIQUEMARKe"

body ="""
This is a Attachment Mail
"""
part1 = """From:from<from@domain.com>
To:to<to@domain.com>
Subject: Sending Attachement
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s
--%s
""" % (marker, marker)

part2 = """Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

%s
--%s
""" % (body,marker)

part3 = """Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"%s\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s

%s--%s--
""" %(filename, filename, encodedcontent, marker)
message = part1 + part2 + part3

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, reciever, message)
   print "Successfully sent email"
except Exception:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Comment: Do you receive this mail at all? If so, how does it look like? Are there the expected headers? Is the body part present?

Comment: I received the mail but only the body part...."This is a Attachment Mail".

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the file to be attached in binary mode, so that your `encodedcontent` is of type `bytes` (that's OK). Then you format it without converting to a string. As a result, your `message` contains `b'....'`  (that's not OK).